# MongoDB aggregation Shell script to MongoC# Driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, shell, mongodb-.net-driver, mongo-shell

How can I convert this Mongo Shell script to MongoDB C# Driver?

```
var myItems = []

var myCursor = db.Tickets.aggregate(
   [
      { $match : { TicketProjectID : 49 } },
      { $project: { TicketProjectID:1, TicketID:1, concatValue: { $concat: [ "$Status", " - ", "$Name" ] } } }
    // I will have a list of fields that I need to concatenate at run time. So C# query should support concatenation for "N" number of fields at run-time.
      //{ $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 } } }

   ],
      { allowDiskUse: true }
)

   //This seems like a ugly performance approach when we are working against 100k results with above match
     while (myCursor.hasNext()) {
         var item = myCursor.next();
         if(item.concatValue.search(/mysearchkey/i) > -1)
             {
                myItems.push(item.TicketID)
             }
    }    
    myItems
```

or is there a better way to do the string search in concatenated projection instead of foreach in cursor, as some quires might get 50k records.

**This is what I have tried so far**, (Not using Aggregation)

Note: Trimmed this code to suite for public Q&A sites. So please consider this as Pseudo-code

```
 var tickets = ticketsCollection.FindSync(filter).ToList();
                string concatinatedValue = string.Empty;
                foreach (var ticket in tickets)
                {
                    foreach (var field in customFieldsForThisProject)
                        concatinatedValue += ticket[field.Replace(" ", "_")];

                  if(concatinatedValue.StripHtml().contains("MysearchWord"))
                 {
                   TikectIdList.Add(ticket["TicketID"])
                 }
                }
```

Comment: @KDecker updated question with what I have tried. I did not try using Aggregation with C# Driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Edited according to the given comment*

If you can use AsQueryable() you can get the values like this:

```
var dbResult = from ticket in ticketsCollection.AsQueryable()
               where ticket.TicketProjectID == 49
               select new 
               {
                   TicketProjectID = ticket.TicketProjectID,
                   TicketID = ticket.TicketID,
                   ConcatValue = ticket.Status + " - " + ticket.Name
               };
```

and than later you can do something like this:

```
var result = from dbr in dbResult
             where dbr.ConcatValue.Contains("something") //or
             where dbr.ConcatValue.StartsWith("something")//or you can use regex
             select dbr;
```

> Note: For some reason both `Status` and `Name` properties from type `Ticket` need to be of a type `String` for concatenation to work since mongo driver won't recognize the call to `ToString()` from some other type.

If you want to concatenate properties from some other types you could get them separately from the db and than concat them locally.

`note, i'm not that good with mongo shell i could mess something up but you can see in which way you could go`

Alternatively you could write your shell command like this and put it in a string:

```
var command = @"db.Tickets.aggregate(
[
    { $project: { TicketProjectID:1, TicketID:1, concatValue: { $concat: [ "$Status", " - ", "$Name" ] } } },
    { $match : { TicketProjectId : 49, concatValue : { $regex : /mysearchkey/i } } }
],
{ allowDiskUse : true }
);";
```

then execute it in c# with `RunCommandAsync` method from `MongoDatabase`.

```
var result = await mongoDatabase.RunCommandAsync<BsonDocument>(BsonDocument.Parse(command));
```

Comment: TicketProjectID = 1 indicates include this field in result and ignore rest.

Comment: I need this dynamic, "ticket.Status + " - " + ticket.Name" I will have a list of fields that I need to concatenate, so how can I construct this concatenation at run time?

Comment: then i think that your current solution is what you get, unless you have a possibility to inject something like [LinqToQueryString](http://linqtoquerystring.net/examples.html) between your query and mongodb driver

Comment: can I execute Shell script as is from C#?

Comment: i've edited the answer, maybe you could try something like that

Comment: command is not valid JSON to pass in RunCommand, it cannot start with db.Tickets

Comment: Had to make some more changes, but could finally get what I need

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @Nikola.Lukovic, working on his pseudo-code, I came up with this working solution.

**Approach one:** fully using C# Driver

```
var ticketsCollection = _mongoConnect.Database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Tickets");

            var dbResult = from ticket in ticketsCollection.AsQueryable()
                select new
                {
                    TicketProjectID = ticket["TicketProjectID"],
                    TicketID = ticket["TicketID"],
                    ConcatValue = ticket["Status"] + (string) ticket["Name"]
                };
            var matches = from dbr in dbResult
                where dbr.ConcatValue.Contains(searchKey)
                where dbr.ConcatValue.StartsWith(searchKey)
                select dbr;
```

> This will not work for my scenario as fields I am trying to
>   concatenate are if type string, but `$add` will only work with
>   `numeric` and `date` types.

**Approach two:** using `RunCommand` and passing straight Shell command. **This will work for all datatypes. And works for my need as well.**

```
        var projectCommand =
            BsonDocument.Parse(
                "{ $project: { _id: -1, TicketProjectID:1, TicketID:1, concatValue: { $concat: [ \"$Status\", \" - \", \"$Name\" ] } } }");
        var matchCommand =
            BsonDocument.Parse("{ $match: {concatValue: { $regex: '" + searchKey + "', $options: 'i'} } }");

        var pipeline = new[] {projectCommand, matchCommand};
        var result = ticketsCollection.Aggregate<BsonDocument>(pipeline).ToList();
        if (result.Count > 0)
            return result.Select(x => (int)x["TicketID"]).ToList();
        return null;
```